# Substituting a method with const qualifier change (C++)

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, member

Suppose we need to instantiate a function that calls some class method from inside non-trivial code.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
   int f() { return 1; }
   int g() { return 2; }
};

template <class T, int (T::*method)()>
int func(T& x)
{
   // some complex code here calling method()
   return (x.*method)();
}

int main()
{
   A a;
   std::cout << func<A, &A::f>(a) << "\n"
             << func<A, &A::g>(a) << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

This code compiles and works fine. Now suppose that the two methods are actually const and non-const, like this:

```
class A
{
   int val_;
public:
   A() : val_(0) {}
   int alloc() { return ++val_; }
   int get() const { return val_; }
};
```

This time we can't use the same approach, because the member functions have different signatures due to const qualifier. Moving the problem to run time does not seem to solve anything, Is there a way to avoid rewriting func() as two functions in this situation?

Comment: Can you encapsulate your 'complex code' somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Can you change passing method from template parameter to function parameter?
If yes, this works:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
   int f() { return 1; }
   int g() const { return 2; }
};

template <class T, class F>
int func(F method, T& x)
{
   // some complex code here calling method()
   return (x.*method)();
}

int main()
{
   A a;
   std::cout << func(&A::f, a) << "\n"
             << func(&A::g, a) << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a way to solve this problem. I just noticed you used 'class F' for a method pointer, which I have to research. Maybe this feature is exactly to solve situations like these.

Comment: And so it will also work for any combinations of `const` `volatile` l/r value reference methods.